# Disable rotate, pan and pinch zoom gestures

Tags: c#, winforms, gestures

I'm trying to disable most of the touch gestures that can effect my WebBrowser control in my winforms project and i've been unsuccessfull so far.

- Edge Gestures have been disabled with PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullScreen => working
- I'm using a PreFilterMessage but it seems that WM_GESTURE can't be filtered from there :

  ```
  public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
  {
      // Messages to be filtered
      const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;
      const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
      const int WM_GESTURE = 0x0119;
      const int WM_GESTURENOTIFY = 0x011A;
      const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

      switch (m.Msg)
      {
          case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
              Debug.WriteLine("Filtering WM_MOUSEWHEEL !"); // Working
              return true;

          case WM_GESTURE:
              Debug.WriteLine("Filtering WM_GESTURE !"); // Not working
              return true;

          case WM_GESTURENOTIFY:
              Debug.WriteLine("Filtering WM_GESTURENOTIFY !"); // Not working
              return true;

          case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
              int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
              if (command == SC_MOVE) return true;
              break;
      }
  ```
- Next i've moved to WndProc override and i see the messages in debug log but so far i haven't figured out how to filter message from there: the gesture got executed anyway.

  ```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
      const int WM_GESTURE = 0x0119;
      const int WM_GESTURENOTIFY = 0x011A;
      switch (m.Msg)
      {             
          case WM_GESTURE:
              Debug.WriteLine("WM_GESTURE go away !!!");
              return;

          case WM_GESTURENOTIFY:
              Debug.WriteLine("WM_GESTURENOTIFY begone with thee !!");
              return;
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
  ```

i try to avoid CSS injection in the html page or setting a registry value to globally disable zoom in internet explorer, anyone has an idea ?

Comment: New unsuccessful attempt : using SetGestureConfig inside my WndProc override with the following GESTURECONFIG block :
dwID = 0;
dwWant = 0;
dwBlock = GC_ALLGESTURES;

i'm firing SetGestureConfig  upon WM_GESTURENOTIFY message, but i'm still able to zoom my WinForm's WebBrowser :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question :)

Filtering WM_GESUTURE and WM_TOUCH messages out have led to nowhere (never noticed a change in the app touch behavior)

[WM_POINTER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454904(v=vs.85).aspx) is the way to go... Filetering WM_POINTERUP and WM_POINTERDOWN messages has an effect on my application.

Working with WM_POINTER messages gives low level datas and you have to build your own gesture interpretation (which looks like a real pain, if your goal is only to disable theses)

The workaround : since WM_POINTER carries info about primary, secondary, ternary pointers, i filter out all the messages not related to primary pointer, thus disabling two fingers

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    internal static int HIWORD(IntPtr wParam)
    {
        return (int)((wParam.ToInt64() >> 16) & 0xffff);
    }

    internal static int LOWORD(IntPtr wParam)
    {
        return (int)(wParam.ToInt64() & 0xffff);
    }
    [Flags]
    internal enum VIRTUAL_KEY_STATES
    {
        NONE = 0x0000,
        LBUTTON = 0x0001,
        RBUTTON = 0x0002,
        SHIFT = 0x0004,
        CTRL = 0x0008,
        MBUTTON = 0x0010,
        XBUTTON1 = 0x0020,
        XBUTTON2 = 0x0040
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
        public POINT(Point pt)
        {
            X = pt.X;
            Y = pt.Y;
        }
        public Point ToPoint()
        {
            return new Point(X, Y);
        }
        public void AssignTo(ref Point destination)
        {
            destination.X = X;
            destination.Y = Y;
        }
        public void CopyFrom(Point source)
        {
            X = source.X;
            Y = source.Y;
        }
        public void CopyFrom(POINT source)
        {
            X = source.X;
            Y = source.Y;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public RECT(Rectangle source)
        {
            Left = source.Left;
            Top = source.Top;
            Right = source.Right;
            Bottom = source.Bottom;
        }
        public RECT(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            Left = x;
            Top = y;
            Right = Left + width;
            Bottom = Top + height;
        }
        public int Width
        {
            get { return Right - Left; }
        }
        public int Height
        {
            get { return Bottom - Top; }
        }
        public Rectangle ToRectangle()
        {
            return new Rectangle(Left, Top, Width, Height);
        }
        public void Inflate(int dx, int dy)
        {
            Left -= dx;
            Top -= dy;
            Right += dx;
            Bottom += dy;
        }
        public void Deflate(int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin)
        {
            Left += leftMargin;
            Top += topMargin;
            Right -= rightMargin;
            Bottom -= bottomMargin;
            if (Bottom < Top)
            {
                Bottom = Top;
            }
            if (Right < Left)
            {
                Right = Left;
            }
        }
        public void Offset(int dx, int dy)
        {
            Left += dx;
            Top += dy;
            Right += dx;
            Bottom += dy;
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum TOUCH_FLAGS
    {
        NONE = 0x00000000
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum TOUCH_MASK
    {
        NONE = 0x00000000,
        CONTACTAREA = 0x00000001,
        ORIENTATION = 0x00000002,
        PRESSURE = 0x00000004,
    }

    internal enum POINTER_INPUT_TYPE
    {
        POINTER = 0x00000001,
        TOUCH = 0x00000002,
        PEN = 0x00000003,
        MOUSE = 0x00000004
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum POINTER_FLAGS
    {
        NONE = 0x00000000,
        NEW = 0x00000001,
        INRANGE = 0x00000002,
        INCONTACT = 0x00000004,
        FIRSTBUTTON = 0x00000010,
        SECONDBUTTON = 0x00000020,
        THIRDBUTTON = 0x00000040,
        FOURTHBUTTON = 0x00000080,
        FIFTHBUTTON = 0x00000100,
        PRIMARY = 0x00002000,
        CONFIDENCE = 0x00004000,
        CANCELED = 0x00008000,
        DOWN = 0x00010000,
        UPDATE = 0x00020000,
        UP = 0x00040000,
        WHEEL = 0x00080000,
        HWHEEL = 0x00100000,
        CAPTURECHANGED = 0x00200000,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct POINTER_TOUCH_INFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public POINTER_INFO PointerInfo;
        public TOUCH_FLAGS TouchFlags;
        public TOUCH_MASK TouchMask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public RECT ContactArea;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public RECT ContactAreaRaw;
        public uint Orientation;
        public uint Pressure;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct POINTER_INFO
    {
        public POINTER_INPUT_TYPE pointerType;
        public int PointerID;
        public int FrameID;
        public POINTER_FLAGS PointerFlags;
        public IntPtr SourceDevice;
        public IntPtr WindowTarget;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public POINT PtPixelLocation;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public POINT PtPixelLocationRaw;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public POINT PtHimetricLocation;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public POINT PtHimetricLocationRaw;
        public uint Time;
        public uint HistoryCount;
        public uint InputData;
        public VIRTUAL_KEY_STATES KeyStates;
        public long PerformanceCount;
        public int ButtonChangeType;
    }

    internal const int

       WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210,
       WM_NCPOINTERUPDATE = 0x0241,
       WM_NCPOINTERDOWN = 0x0242,
       WM_NCPOINTERUP = 0x0243,
       WM_POINTERUPDATE = 0x0245,
       WM_POINTERDOWN = 0x0246,
       WM_POINTERUP = 0x0247,
       WM_POINTERENTER = 0x0249,
       WM_POINTERLEAVE = 0x024A,
       WM_POINTERACTIVATE = 0x024B,
       WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED = 0x024C,
       WM_POINTERWHEEL = 0x024E,
       WM_POINTERHWHEEL = 0x024F,

       // WM_POINTERACTIVATE return codes
       PA_ACTIVATE = 1,
       PA_NOACTIVATE = 3,

       MAX_TOUCH_COUNT = 256;
    internal static int GET_POINTER_ID(IntPtr wParam)
    {
        return LOWORD(wParam);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool GetPointerInfo(int pointerID, ref POINTER_INFO pointerInfo);       

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {            
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_POINTERDOWN:
            case WM_POINTERUP:
            case WM_POINTERUPDATE:
            case WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED:
                int pointerID = GET_POINTER_ID(m.WParam);
                POINTER_INFO pi = new POINTER_INFO();
                if (GetPointerInfo(pointerID, ref pi))
                {
                    // Not a primary pointer => filter !
                    if ((pi.PointerFlags & POINTER_FLAGS.PRIMARY) == 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;                                   
        }           
        return false;
    }
```